# Несколько изображений в фоне Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, в качестве основного элемента окна использую Border, как фон - изображение. Но оно слишком маленькое, и как результат очень сильно растягивается, что не очень хорошо смотрится. Я хотел бы узнать, как в фоне несколько раз использовать одно и тоже изображение(бесшовное), во избежание пикселезации? И как динамически изменять количество этих изображений?

Вот XAML код:

```
<Style x:Key="border_main" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 0 0 60"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image.jpg"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, надо уложить изображение "плиткой". Это можно сделать, установив `TileMode="Tile"`, в `Viewport` указать размеры изображения в пикселях и переключить `ViewportUnits` в `Absolute`.

Пример для изображения размером 32х32:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Image.jpg" 
            Viewport="0,0,32,32"
            ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
            TileMode="Tile"/>
```

Количество изображений менять не получится, заполняется вся площадь контрола.